# Using the YouTube API and iPhone SDK, how would I get information about a search result?

Tags: iphone, ios, search, youtube-api

I'm trying to simply search for videos using a query, which is working perfectly using the below code.

```
  // Create a service object for executing queries
GTLServiceYouTube *service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
// Services which do not require sign-in may need an API key from the
// API Console
service.APIKey = @"AIzaSy...";
// Create a query
GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSearchListWithPart:@"id,snippet"];
query.maxResults = 10;
query.q = searchBar.text;
query.videoEmbeddable = @"true";
query.type = @"video";
//query.country = @"US";
// Execute the query
GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [service executeQuery:query
                               completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
                                   // This callback block is run when the fetch completes
                                   if (error == nil) {
                                       GTLYouTubeSearchListResponse *products = object;
                                       
                                       [videoArray removeAllObjects];
                                       // iteration of items and subscript access to items.
                                       for (GTLYouTubeSearchResult *item in products) {
                                           
                                           
                                           
                                           NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [item JSONValueForKey:@"id"];
                                           
                                           NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"videoId"]);
                                           YoutubeVideo *video = [[YoutubeVideo alloc]init];
                                           [video setLblTitle:item.snippet.title];
                                           
                                           //Get youtube video image
                                           [video setImgIconURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.snippet.thumbnails.defaultProperty.url]];
                                           
                                           
                                           [video setLblVideoURL:[dictionary objectForKey:@"videoId"]];
                                           
                                           [video setLblChannelTitle:item.snippet.channelTitle];
                                           [videoArray addObject:video];
                                           
                                                                                          
                                       }
                                       reloadData = YES;
                                       [tableView reloadData];
                                       
                                       //Download images asynchronously
                                       [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(downloadImages)
                                                                toTarget:self
                                                              withObject:nil];
                                   }else{
                                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                   }
                               }];
```

However, now I'd like to display certain information about the video. Some of this information I can get out of

```
  item.snippet
```

But I also need to get the video duration, and number of views. How can I get them using Youtube API 3.0?? I also had an idea to try using GData just for this, but it literally triples the load time to use

```
  NSString *JSONString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/%@?v=2&alt=json", [video lblVideoURL]]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil ];
```

How do I get the duration of the video, plus the number of views the video has?

Comment: Your sample works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search query only accept ID and Snippet as parts.  If you change to Video List Query you can include other parts, but you have to use one of the filters.

I think you'll have to get the video ID with the search query and do another query (Now a video query) filtering by ID (the Id you got), than you can get all other information of the videos you searched.

The problem is i'm having trouble getting the video ID, i think the API use the word "identifier" instead of "id" because it's a reserved word of objective-c.

Edit: Yeah, it was just a matter of time, just request my GTLYoutubeSearchResponse.JSON, an manipulated it as i wanted.

FIRST QUERY:

```
GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSearchListWithPart:@"id,snippet"];
query.maxResults = 10;
query.q = @"iphone";
query.fields = @"items(id,snippet)";
query.order = @"viewCount";
//query.channelId = @"UCsnbNwitAF9BzjjdMfRyK2g";//Kavaco

[appDelegate.service executeQuery:query
    completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                        id object,
                        NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            appDelegate.videos = object;

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"videoList" sender:self];

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
        }
    }];
```

SECOND QUERY: In my TableViewController, inside my cellForRowAtIndexPath i do another query for each video i found. Be sure to request only the variables you need to avoid spending your credits, in my case i requested only viewCount.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

GTLYouTubeVideo *video = appDelegate.videos[indexPath.row];

NSMutableDictionary *videoIdJson = [video.JSON objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString *videoId = [videoIdJson objectForKey:@"videoId"];

cell.textLabel.text = video.snippet.title;


GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForVideosListWithPart:@"statistics"];
query.identifier = videoId;
query.maxResults = 1;
query.fields = @"items/statistics(viewCount)";

[appDelegate.service executeQuery:query
                completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                    id object,
                                    NSError *error) {
                    if (error == nil) {
                        GTLYouTubeVideoListResponse *detalhe = object;

                        NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = detalhe.JSON;
                        NSArray *tempArray = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"items"];
                        NSMutableDictionary *items = tempArray[0];
                        NSMutableDictionary *statistics = [items objectForKey:@"statistics"];

                        _views = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Views: %@",[statistics objectForKey:@"viewCount"]];
                        cell.detailTextLabel.text = _views;

                    }
                    else {
                        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                    }
                }];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = _views;


return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its really bad idea make this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

Collect the id from search API and do another video list API call is the proper way to do what you want to achieve. The video list API call can put multiple video ids separate by comma in the same call. The extra call shouldn't consider exhausting because this is [expected behavior](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4332) on API v3:

> *Project Member #1 je...@google.com*
>
> That's the **expected behavior**, and not likely to change. Since the
>   search.list() method can return channels, videos, and playlists, only
>   properties that make sense for all of those resource types are
>   returned in the search responses. If you need to obtain any other
>   properties, making a follow-up request to, e.g., videos.list() is
>   required. Note that you can pass in up to 50 video ids to
>   videos.list(), so you can effectively look up an entire page's worth
>   of search.list() results in a single video.list() call.

If you try https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it , you set **contentDetails,statistics** as the part, you should able to get the following result:

> "contentDetails": {
>       "duration": "PT20M38S",
>       "dimension": "2d",
>       "definition": "hd",
>       "caption": "false",
>       "licensedContent": false
>      },
>
> "statistics": {
>       "viewCount": "191",
>       "likeCount": "7",
>       "dislikeCount": "0",
>       "favoriteCount": "0",
>       "commentCount": "0"
>      }

**PT20M38S** means 20 minutes and 38 seconds, based on ISO 8601(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: search quary does not take contentDetails,statistics as part paramters @林果皞

Answer (score 0):

The best way for make this is:

```
if (!service) {
        service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
        service.shouldFetchNextPages = YES;
        service.shouldFetchInBackground = YES;
        service.retryEnabled = YES;
        service.APIKey = @"AIzaSyDSO2JPnM_r9VcDrDJJs_d_7Li2Ttk2AuU";
    }
    [youtubeList removeAllObjects];

    GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSearchListWithPart:@"id"];
    query.maxResults = 50;
    query.q = withText;
    query.fields = @"items(id)";
    query.order = @"viewCount";
    query.type = @"video";
//    query.videoDuration = @"long";//any-long-medium-short

    __block NSInteger incrementRequest = 0;
    [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error is!! = %@", error.localizedDescription);
            return;
        }
        GTLYouTubeVideoListResponse *idsResponse = object;
        for (GTLYouTubeVideoListResponse *videoInfo in object) {
            [youtubeList addObject:videoInfo.JSON];

            GTLQueryYouTube *query2 = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForVideosListWithIdentifier:[[videoInfo.JSON valueForKey:@"id"] valueForKey:@"videoId"] part:@"id,contentDetails,snippet,statistics"];
            query2.maxResults = 1;
            query2.fields = @"items(id,contentDetails,snippet,statistics)";
            query2.order = @"viewCount";

            [service executeQuery:query2 completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error is!! = %@", error.localizedDescription);
                    return;
                }
                GTLYouTubeVideoListResponse *detalhe = object;

                for (NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict in youtubeList) {
                    if ([[[tmpDict valueForKey:@"id"] valueForKey:@"videoId"] isEqualToString:[[[detalhe.JSON valueForKey:@"items"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"id"]]) {
                        [tmpDict removeObjectForKey:@"id"];
                        //condition personal
                        if (![Utils parseISO8601TimeIsGrater30:[[[[detalhe.JSON valueForKey:@"items"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"contentDetails"] valueForKey:@"duration"]]) {
                            BOOL isBlockedInUs = NO;
                            for (NSString *countryRestric in [[[[[detalhe.JSON valueForKey:@"items"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"contentDetails"] valueForKey:@"regionRestriction"] valueForKey:@"blocked"]) {
                                if ([countryRestric isEqualToString:@"US"]) {
                                    isBlockedInUs = YES;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!isBlockedInUs) {
                                [tmpDict addEntriesFromDictionary:detalhe.JSON];
                                [tmpDict setValue:[[[[detalhe.JSON valueForKey:@"items"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"snippet"] valueForKey:@"publishedAt"] forKey:@"publishedAt"];
                            } else {
                                [youtubeList removeObject:tmpDict];
                            }
                        } else {
                            [youtubeList removeObject:tmpDict];
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }

                incrementRequest ++;
                if ([idsResponse.items count] == incrementRequest) {
                    //Finish
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
```